# How to stop the background scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a case in which the background is scrolling and contains image thumbnails upon clicking it should animate the actual pic.
I am done with everything ,when i click on the thumbnail ,the image pops up,but i want the background to be silent (no scrolling is required).It is still scrolling ,how to stop that

here is my custom.js ,what should i add to achieve that

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.space-image').click(function() {
        var image_sel_id = $(this).attr('id');
        /*$('.transparent').show();
        /*$('.gallery-wrapper').hide(1000);*/
        $('#fullimage'+image_sel_id).show().animate({left:'5%',width:'90%'},"slow");
        $('#scrollimage').attr("disabled","disabled").off('click');


    });

    $('.fullimagecont').click(function() {
        var image_clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');
        /*$('.transparent').hide().animate({width:'20%'},"slow");
        /*$('.gallery-wrapper').show(1000);*/
        $('#'+image_clicked_id).hide().animate({width:'20%'},500);


    });
});
```

Here is the html part

```
<div class="content_area">
    <div class="transparent" style="display:none;width:100%;height:100%;float:left;position:relative;z-index:900;"></div>
    <div class="fullimagecont" id="fullimage5">
        <img src="img/5.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="fullimagecont" id="fullimage6">
        <img src="img/6.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="fullimagecont" id="fullimage7">
        <img src="img/7.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="fullimagecont" id="fullimage8">
        <img src="img/8.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="fullimagecont" id="fullimage10">
        <img src="img/10.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-wrapper" id="scrollimage" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;line-height:0;">
        <img src="img/gallery/5.jpg" class="space-image" id="5"
        /><img src="img/gallery/7.jpg" class="space-image" id="7"
        /><img src="img/gallery/8.jpg" class="space-image" id="8"
        /><img src="img/gallery/10.jpg" class="space-image" id="10"
        /><img src="img/gallery/6.jpg" class="space-image" id="6" />
    </div>

    <div class="div-slide-effect">


    </div>


</div>
```

PLease help

Here is the .css

```
.fullimagecont
{
  position:absolute;display:none;width:25%;height:100%;left:5%;top:0;z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: please post relevant css and/or, make a jsfiddle.

Comment: If @Ranveer is watching this: **do not add whitespaces**. They are not meaningless. `/>` on the next line directly attached to the next tag is one of the known idioms to get rid of them (others are simply joining lines and adding comments).

Comment: @ ZYx u r correct ,but i can not make separate edits so,
I accepted that .

Comment: @ZyX thanks for the info. Will keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fix it

Set the overflow property of the body `hidden`,on the click of the popup open event

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

and set it to `auto` on popup close

```
 $('body').css('overflow','auto');
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: u mean to add it inside the on click function or how is it
can u describe a bit???

Comment: @N.Nihar, yeah add  $('body').css('overflow','hidden');inside the click function which displays the popup  and add this $('body').css('overflow','auto'); inside the function which close the poup

Comment: @N.Nihar try it and please respond.

Comment: I just finished with all probable combinations nothing worked for my case,in one of the scenarios only clicking on the thumbnail image was restricted not the background.

I am a new comer ,may be going wrong i have put the code
can u point out the exact piece of code.

Comment: I will have paste a demo

Comment: u mean u will post or u r refering to u r old post

Comment: @N.Nihar I think you can understand it from the sample code on how it works, check the scrollbar on both close and click

Comment: that is not exact,in my scenario when i  click the close button then only the background should move not the "close".In this case both are vanishing.

Comment: @N.Nihar what is vanishing, you mean

Comment: the red background ,urs is stationary in mine case it is scrolling 
i just want the background to be sattionary(scrolling effect to be removed),not vanishing

Comment: i just tried editing ur fiddle ,u can try that u can see there will be 5 images ,those which are scrolling,(not here though),if i click one i pic pops up and the background should be silent(no scrolling).
I hope u get my problem

Comment: may be you can share that fiddle